# Windows 7 with samba logon issue

Tags: windows-7, login, samba, ldap

I am running a Debian server with Samba and LDAP. I can log in to any Win7 client workstation as any user except one. Let's call this user *baduser*. When I try to log in as *baduser* (on any workstation), I get the error:

> there are currently no logon servers available to service the login request

The LDAP password for this user was recently changed and the updated password is recognised elsewhere (for eg, email, ssh) but I can't seem to login to a Windows workstation.

I've had a look through other posts but none of them seem to indicate a similar situation where only one user is having trouble.